# Rails respond_with acting different in index and create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am building a simple json API in Rails 3.1. I created a controller that has two functions:

```
class Api::DogsController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :json, :xml
  def index
    respond_with({:msg => "success"})
  end

  def create
    respond_with({:msg => "success"})
  end
end
```

In routes.rb I have

```
namespace :api do 
  resources :dogs
end
```

When I make a get request to http://localhost:3000/api/dogs I get the correct json from above. When I make a post to the same url, I get a rails exception:

```
ArgumentError in Api::DogsController#create
Nil location provided. Can't build URI.
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:183:in `build_named_route_call`
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:120:in `polymorphic_url'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:145:in `url_for'
```

But if I change the create code to

```
def create
  respond_with do |format|
    format.json { render :json => {:msg => "success"}}
  end
end
```

it returns the json just fine.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 38):

After coming across this issue myself and overcoming it, I believe I can supply an answer.

When you simply say:

```
def create
  respond_with({:msg => "success"})
end
```

What rails tries to do is "guess" a url that the newly created resource is available at, and place it in the [HTTP location header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location). That guess fails miserably for a hash object (the location it deduces is nil, which leads to the error message you are seeing).

To overcome this issue, then, you would need to do the following:

```
def create
  respond_with({:msg => "success"}, :location => SOME_LOCATION)
end
```

Assuming that you know where the new resource is located. You can even specify "nil" as "SOME_LOCATION" and that will work (somewhat absurdly).

Comment: Setting location to the string literal "nil" worked: `respond_with({:error => "bad"}, :status => 401, :location => "nil")`

Comment: @kwbeam I was talking about an actual nil value in the last paragraph (I realize now that the quotes may have been a tad misleading)

Comment: I did think you meant nil the object, not the string literal, but when I tried it, it still failed.  However, I just changed it back to nil (the object, not the string literal) and it is working.  So apparently I had a fail somewhere, but I'm not able to reconstruct what I did wrong.  Sorry for the confusion.  (I had updated the version of Rails and many gems in the interim, so perhaps there was a bug that got fixed...but I'm not sure)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had this same problem and this solved it. If StackOverflow would allow me, I would vote you up twice. Thanks!

Comment: +1 - Helped me too! Thanks so much! Note: I just set my location to "" and it worked fine for me.

Comment: fyi if you're responding with a json object, the location should be set to the path to that object, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem myself.

It is, like Aubergine says, something related with the http location header.

Actually, rails seems to build this location using by default the `show route`.

If you don't have a `show action`, -which is weird in an API, but can happen (i think)`, then you have to set a location by yourself. I have no idea what is the standard in this case.

If it happens that you need a show route, then code it, and everything should work fine.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that
   errors = {:error => @device.errors.full_messages}
   respond_with( errors, :status => :bad_request, :location => nil)
works. The :location is required and setting it to nil helps when using with spec:
   expect(last_response.status).not_to eql 201
   expect(last_response.location).to be_nil

The problem I was having is that I was not returning the errors hash, just the status. Adding the errors hash and setting the location myself solved it.