# respond_with is asking for location on error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, respond-with

I have a pretty standard authenticate method

```
  private

  def authenticate_user
    @current_user = User.find_by_authentication_token(params[:token])
    unless @current_user
      error = { :error => "Invalid token." }
      respond_with(error, :status => 401 )
    end
  end
```

I am calling the API to ensure the authenticate fails.

I get an error stating

```
ArgumentError (Nil location provided. Can't build URI.):
  app/controllers/api/v1/base_controller.rb:13:in `authenticate_user'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the code in `base_controller.rb`? Which line is line 13?

Comment: The method is private so we need to know where/how it is called.  Please show how/where you are calling this method in the controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the specific flavor of your error, I am guessing that "authenticate_user" is called as part of a "create" action.

If that is the case, I believe the answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303551/rails-respond-with-acting-different-in-index-and-create-method/8136297#8136297) will help you as well.

Assuming, however, that this is part of creating an authenticated session, meaning there is no actual location for the newly created "resource", I would supply nil for the response location, as in:

```
...
respond_with(error, :status => 401, :location => nil)
...
```

That will make more sense once you have a look at the linked answer. If it still doesn't make sense, I'll be happy to clarify.

Comment: Hi, I did this and still the same problem,   respond_with(:ec => 200, :em => "None", :places => @places,:location => nil)

Comment: @gal That would be very difficult considering I know nothing about your exact problem. Why not open another question if nothing on the site seems to help you specific predicament?

Answer (score 0):

I changed respond_with to render and it worked:

```
render json: { success: false, message: "an error" }, status: 500
```