# ajax only recognising json if I create it manually

Tags: ruby, ajax, json, handsontable

I am trying to use the following code to check that data is being saved:

```
$parent.find('button[name=save]').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/help.json",
    data: {"data": handsontable.getData()}, //returns all cells' data
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (res) {
      if (res.result === 'ok') {
        $console.text('Data saved');
      }
      else {
        $console.text('Save error');
      }
    },
    error: function () {
      $console.text('Save error, not working');
    }
  });
});
```

I am using rails for the server side code. If I manually create /help.json.erb and add the following to the page

```
{
  "result": "ok"
}
```

The I get a 'Data saved' message when I try the ajax code.

However, if I try to create the /help.json file with ruby I get an 'Save error, not working' error. My ruby code to create the /help.json file is as follows in my controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
 respond_to :html, :json

  def home
  end

  def help
      the_hash = {"result"=>"ok"}
      respond_with(the_hash) 
  end
end
```

The above codes generates a /help.json file with

```
{"result": "ok"}
```

But I don't get the 'Data saved' message

What could be the reason that it works when I manually create the json file but not if I try with ruby?

The relevant part of my routes file is:

```
  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
```

On further inspection, the error message I am getting in 500 (internal server error)

Comment: Could you post the routes.rb (at least the relevant lines pertaining to that controller) and more of the controller code?

Comment: Could you try a `curl -v` to your end point, and see if there any differences in the returned headers?

Comment: @fmendez I have added more of the code from my controller and routes file

Comment: @NeilSlater I am sorry I am not sure how to do a curl -v to my endpoint

Comment: Seems like you solved your own issue. For the record, from the command line while your service is running: `curl -v http://<server>:<port>/help.json`  should display all the headers as well as body of response - a handy quick test of the Ruby server-side so you can figure out whether it's the Ruby or JavaScript you need to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the answer here:

[Rails respond_with acting different in index and create method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303551/rails-respond-with-acting-different-in-index-and-create-method)

I changed my respond_with statement to:

```
   respond_with({:result => "ok"}, :location => nil)
```