# undefined method {....}_url when calling create in api controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm working on a rails app that serves some json and I'm having hard time understanding what is going on in the code below (simplified for the purpose of understanding the issue).

```
module Api
  class ProjectController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def show
       x = {"id"=>17, "name"=>"abc", "version"=>1}
       respond_with x.to_json, status: 200
    end

    def create
      x = {"id"=>17, "name"=>"abc", "version"=>1}
      respond_with x.to_json, status: 200
    end
  end
end
```

The show action works fine but when I call the create action I get

NoMethodError (undefined method '{"id":17,"name":"abc","version":1}_url' for
Api::ProjectsController:0x007fbb2294cd18)

Why do I get this error while show works just fine? is it because create makes a post instead of a get?

How can I solve it?

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Comment: Why are you returning ` Hash` object rather than an instance of the `Project` class?

Comment: it is because the project object is in a second app. The second app returns is as json 
`def create
 respond_with  Project.create(project_params)
end`
to the main app (the 1 I have issue with) and the main app forwards it to the original caller.

Comment: Looks like that adding location:nil solves the issue
`respond_with x.to_json, status: 200, location: nil`

Why is this happening?  Thanks

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303551/rails-respond-with-acting-different-in-index-and-create-method

Comment: Thanks Tihom for your reply

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your controller is in a module (`Api`). That affects the namespace, and thus the routing; you must include that namespace as part of what you pass to `respond_with`.

Normally, I'd direct you to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23583414/135101) (credit goes there). But since you are using a hash instead of a model, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8136297/135101) might be more applicable.

Note how Rails is trying to call a `..._url` method. The `...` is your hash, in JSON format. You need to help Rails here on how to render.