# How to stop redirect after POST/create in rails API - NoMethodError (undefined method `users_url' for #<UsersController:0x00007f91363ebee8>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple (one table) API and want to stop an error message appearing after a successful POST/create.

#### Background

The create action looks like so

```rb
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user


    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
    end
```

When I post new data into the User model, it works (i.e. the data saves to the database)

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"name": "IIII", "email": "IIIII"}' "http://localhost:3000/users/somekey"
```

#### The problem

Although the POST works, I get the following error

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 61ms (ActiveRecord: 20.2ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `user_url' for #<UserssController:0x00007f91363ebee8>):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

The error occurs because after the POST, [rails tries to redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23583414/5783745) to `users_url`, and because my routes are a little different (i.e. they contain `:key`, like so: `post 'users/:key' => 'users#create'`), the `users_url` route fails.

#### My question

How do I stop rails attempting to redirect after the successful POST/create?

Comment: I think the redirect is triggered by `location: @user` argument of the render, try to remove this part

Comment: @colinux that solved it, thanks very much. You can make that the answer if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comment, the problem was the `location` argument of a `render` which trigger a redirection.

The solution is to remove `location: @user` of the render.